# Java / Android: Get Facebook User Info From Graph Api, Display in TextView

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, textview

I'm trying to learn Java right now and I've jumped in the deep end by starting with the Android Faceobok API. Right now, I'm trying to get some information from my graph data (a friend in this case) and display it in a text view. This seems rather trivial but it has been anything but.

```
JSONObject json_data = null;

    try
    {
        JSONObject response = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("/me/friends", mBundle, "GET")); // Get a friend information from facebook
        JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String name = json_data.getString("name");
        mText.setText(name);

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (FacebookError e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The TextView doesn't change when I do this and I'm not exactly sure where I've gone wrong.

As an aside, there is a shortage of good Android Facebook API tutorials out there. Most are hundreds of lines of code; I don't have the energy or patience to consume all of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion about being "trivial" is essentially true, but generally speaking "jumping into the deep end" rarely results in anything other than a drowning.

I'm going to be "that guy" and recommend you actually get to the point of having a general understanding and minimal competency in Java before tackling someone else's API.  Once you know how Java works - the "PME" ... properties, methods, and events - learning anyone's API becomes just a question of following the proper steps.

Besides that little bit of PS, answer the following:
1) received data from your source?
2) what thread are you invoking this on?
3) any of the objects null?
4) any exceptions being thrown when you look in the Console or Log (print those out to the Log versus your current implementation)?

And, not for nothing, but if you don't have the time or patience to learn the "how's and why's" of an API or software dev in general then this will be a long exercise for you if the work ever becomes non-trivial.

Just one man's opinion who also has attempted to drink from fire hose before.

Comment: 1) Rephrase this?
2) "onCreate"
3) Nope
4) No

Comment: Good advice on the drowning, too. I never realized moving from C/++/# to Java would be this difficult, but there are many language nuances that are new to me.

Comment: 1) .. are you sure the Server actually sent you back data (the URL)?  Normally you'd have to login first.  If you can do that, then any "real data" you're attempting to query is probably just a syntactial error if you're invoking the proper calls.  As such, what happens when you do authenicate?  I personally think C# and Java are remarkably similar.  I started with Java back in 1997 and was amazed when C# came along that Sun Microsystems was suing MS again, but there's still allot to learn.

Comment: I will check into this. C# is quite similar to Java but perhaps it's the shift from VS to Eclipse that's throwing me off.

Comment: Got it working; this whole concept of activities is over my head. I changed the below code by moving my request to onActivityResult rather than the onCreate method. The most multi-thread programming I've done is using c's fork() and wait() functions. How exactly is my program executing (which order) and what is the proper way to have my request execute in its own thread?

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling your initial request isnt working properly. you should try this line instead:

```
JSONObject response = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/friends"));
```

Firstly I think in your initial request, it should be `"me/friends"` rather than `"/me/friends"`. Secondly you dont necessarily need the  `mBundle`or `"GET"` parameters in what you're trying to achieve. Have you even defined parameters in `mBundle`? You're also getting information from the request method, so the `"GET"` parameter isn't necessary.

Try the line i just wrote, as it is simpler and will get your friends information. The rest of your code is fine.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I don't have enough rep to upvote you; sorry. The whole concept of a bundle is new to me so I used the approach you suggested and - with a few other changes - managed to get it working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update: Here's all of my code:

```
    public class FriendsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("194653157245506");

    TextView mText;
    Bundle mBundle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

mText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text);

        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"offline_access", "user_interests", "friends_interests"},

                new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });

        JSONObject json_data = null;

        try
        {
            JSONObject response = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("/me/friends", mBundle, "GET")); // Get a friend information from facebook
            JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String name = json_data.getString("name");
            Log.i("friend is", name);
            mText.setText(name);

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (FacebookError e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little off key. but I have done facebook api development in C#, and i am wondering if you have had the client login.

Facebook works with OAuth to allow you to authorize through them for a client. (Even your own account as the client) therefore you may need to login.

Another thing to look at is, do you have the TextView that is in the Activity that is being displayed..

Try putting in a breakpoint and looking over the code as it is executing, Debug View is great for that.
see if your response is being populated.
make sure you have the Text from the Activity.

```
mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1); //or whatever you named it.
```

Also the LogCat should show you the stack trace for any errors that occur, maybe posting some of the output would help